# MySQL Create View Tables names from Schema and Count in loop

Tags: mysql

i need some ideas to create a MySQL View.

The base query collect all table names with prefix _dynamicgroup.

```
SELECT table_name AS tname FROM information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME LIKE "%_dynamicgroup%"');
```

As a next step I would like to have the number of individual fields of each table. In each table there is a column "ID".

```
SELECT count(id) FROM 10_dynamicgroup
```

The view should then look like this:

| IDcount | tname |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 10_dynamicgroup |
| 17 | 33_dynamicgroup |
| 27 | 3_dynamicgroup |
| 1 | 56_dynamicgroup |
| 110 | 18_dynamicgroup |

Thank you for your ideas

[image: Unknown Table names]

[image: Example content of table 69_dynamicgroup]

Answer (score 0):

you can use.

SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...

</code

Comment: But in this case and know the table names and have to get the values from table schema at first into a variable and i dont know how to create a sub query.

Answer (score 0):

You should be querying the `information_schema.COLUMNS` table:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS IDcount, TABLE_NAME AS name
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_dynamicgroup%'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: This does not work the value is always "1"

Comment: Thanks Tim, In this case its count only the table name not the content ID in each % _dynamicgroup table

Comment: You should add sample data to your question to make it clear what result you want here.